# What's the process for developing in Python on my Macbook, to run on my Pi?

Tags: python, ssh, macos

I have a Macbook, I have a pi, I have the IP address and have been able to successfully SSH into the Pi from the terminal on the macbook. I also have Textmate.

What I'd like is to be able to open files in textmate, edit, save, then RUN them on the pi, but I'm unsure about the process, steps, setup, etc. I haven't been able to find any good resources that can explain how it's done.

What's the general process for developing remotely on a Pi?

Comment: Look as sshfs, it is a files system over ssh. You can mount a part of the remote machines files system onto the local one. You just need an ssh connection. To make the pi the client end you will have to `sudo aptitude install sshfs` and set up sshd (ssh server) on the mac. For the mac to be the client end look here http://osxfuse.github.io/

Comment: Another option install X11 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuartz) on the mac. Then `ssh -X pi@raspberrypi` you can run any graphical program on the pi and display it locally. Also consider vnc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing for you to do, at least from my perspective, is the following:

1. FTP into your RPi ([See this link for help](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ftp-commands/))
2. Transfer the file over to it (again, see the above link)
3. Run the file with

   python myPythonScript.py

Alternatively, if you're comfortable with it, you could download a program on your rpi to just edit it there via your ssh connection. Nano, pico, and vi are popular terminal-based text editors. Note that you won't have use of your mouse, so it's something to get used to.

Comment: I think `Nano`, `Pico` and `Vi` all come with `Raspbian`. no need to download

Comment: @PhilVallone I assume you're right, but I wasn't sure if he was running raspbian or a different OS on there (as he didn't specify)

Comment: Sorry, it's Raspbian, so you're right. I was able to get up and running exactly like you said, just ran my first sample script remotely and got my RFID Reader working on the first go. Thanks so much. That was a perfectly clear and concise answer.